# How to enter UTF-8 characters inside a jar file using Scanner(System.in)

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, cmd, executable-jar

I have a java project in which i want to take input from the user.
I wrote the code in eclipse and it was running without any problems at all.

However, when I export my classes into an executable-jar file using eclipse and try to run it in the windows cmd, the `Scanner(System.in)` can't read charachters in UTF-8 (greek characters) or something else that i haven't thought about.

This is the part of the code where i run into the problem :

```
String yesORno = inp.stringScanner(); // basically a nextLine()
while (!(yesORno.equals("ΝΑΙ") || yesORno.equals("ΟΧΙ"))) { // ΝΑΙ and OXI are greek characters not latin
    System.out.println("Παρακαλώ πληκτρολογίστε 'ΝΑΙ' ή 'ΟΧΙ'"); // please type ΝΑΙ or ΟΧΙ in greek
    yesORno = inp.stringScanner(); // take input again
}
```

`inp` is an object of an other class which i use to take inputs, in this case with the method `stringScanner()`

```
public String stringScanner() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    return in.nextLine();
}
```

So when i run the code in eclipse and enter some sample characters for testing i get :

[image]

And that's what i want to happen every time.

But when i run the jar file i get :

[image]

As you can see the jar file for some reason doesn't recognise greek NAI and `yesORno.equals("ΝΑΙ")` doesn't return `true` to stop the while loop.

The same happens with OXI

I have tried running the jar file by using a `.bat` file like :

```
start java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar Myfile.jar
```

but no solution.

I've done a lot of reserch to resolve this problem but I have found nothing.

I would appreciate your help

Comment: If you're reading from a file, you should probably be constructing the scanner with ``Scanner inp = new Scanner(file, UTF-8);`` (where file is a File). You could also create it with a Stream and UTF-8.

Comment: Doing `new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8")` should work too.

Comment: Type `chcp 65001` before running your program

Comment: I am trying to read from the user (command line). I tried to use `new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8")` but it didn't work. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I think @NomadMaker is on the right track. For Windows I'd specify the 1253 code page rather than UTF-8.

Answer (score 4):

The JVM argument `-Dfile.encoding` tells the JVM what is the default encoding for (text) files it may encounter. This includes `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` – mapped to `System.in`, `System.out` and `System.err`. But the argument will not change anything in the operating system.

Most probably, your Windows CMD is using the Windows-1253 encoding, not UTF-8. When you tell the JVM with the `-Dfile.encoding` argument that it would be UTF-8, that would be an outright lie …

Try `start java -Dfile.encoding=Windows-1253 -jar Myfile.jar` or `start java -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-7 -jar Myfile.jar`.

If you setup your system with Windows-1253, the second option may cause other problems, as ISO-8859-7 and Windows-1253 are not fully compatible. But for your test it should do the job.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately none of the above solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the way you use the scanner will always depend on the operating system's encoding settings.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.InputStream)

Look at the alternative constructors - you can define the encoding there directly. Your code could look like

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");
```